# Autocomplete Combobox failed to select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I want to use jqueryui autocomplete combobox function to let user choose an option from the list.

I followed this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gB32r/), and here is my code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9vK7/).

And I get this error when I click the option from the list :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'option' of undefined.
```

The error pointed to the line as below :

```
select: function(event, ui) {
     ui.item.option.selected = true;               <-- This Line
     self._trigger("selected", event, {
     item: ui.item.option
  })
},
```

What is the problem with the `option`?

**Edit 2 :**

Seems like the `ui.item` is not assigned to any value, because when I want to display the `ui.item` to console, it returns `undefined` instead of `object`.

But, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is the jqueryui version. In version 1.10.x, data no longer stored in `item.autocomplete`, but `ui-autocomplete-item`.

It's should be :

```
input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

And not

```
input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

You can refer to [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-item-autocomplete-data-use-ui-autocomplete-item).

Answer (score 0):

Try value instead of option if your code mentioned is in autocomplete

`i.item.value` this will give you selected string type value from your combo

For example I want to get the value of selected email from my combo `(#emailstext)`

```
$('#emailstext').autocomplete({
    source: dat,
    minLenght: 1,
    autocomplete: true,
    select: function (e, i) {
        dowhateverwithemail(i.item.value); //this will pass selected value from combo to function
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working. When I changed the `option` to `value`, it gives me error too : `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

Comment: As you said, `ui.item.value` will get the selected value, so I try to display value in console, `console.log(ui.item.value);`.

Comment: I am sure that ui.item.value will give you select value in combo.
why dont you watch this expression in "Inspect Element".

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm doing it correct or not, but you can try on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9vK7/).

Comment: Seems like the problem is the version of jqueryui I used. The example used `1.8.0`, but mine is `1.10.4`. it's a careless mistake I made before checking the version.